# IE8/9 exports .dar file as .zip

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have the following code to export some configs as .dar file:

```
tempDarfile= File.createTempFile(dynamicFileNamewithTimeStamp,".dar", downloadDirectory);
export(tempDarFile);
```

Prior to IE8, I see correct .dar file exported. But in IE8/9 I see .zip extension for file.

Comment: Does this help? http://serverfault.com/questions/40971/stop-ie8-renaming-files-to-zip-when-downloading

Comment: How to set the mine type in JBoss ?